# Spring boot oracle driver at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ojdbc

I have a spring boot app that I am trying to add an oracle connection to. I have already added an @Entity class and Repository.

I have added the oracle ojdbc8.jar to my local maven repo and have this in gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile group: 'com.oracle', name: 'ojdbc8', version:'12.2.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    ...
}
```

my application.properties contains

```
spring.datasource.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname.whatever:1521/blah"
spring.datasource.username="username"
spring.datasource.password="password"
spring.datasource.driver-class-name="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
```

This all compiles fine. But when I deploy (under tomcat) I get

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration':    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
```

Looks like it's having trouble finding the driver. Is there something else I need to do to make it know where to find it? Or to build it as part of the archive?

I also built a similar test app and pointed it at a local mysql just to make sure I wasn't crazy and that works fine... Not sure what's so special about oracle.

Comment: why do you specify property values between `""` characters ?

Comment: @davidxxx I was playing... doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: So please show the whole stracktrace.

Comment: Add the oracle JDBC driver to your dependencies.

Comment: @M. Deinum  It seems that it is specified here  `compile group: 'com.oracle', name: 'ojdbc8', version:'12.2.0'`

Comment: Purge your local maven repository then and rebuild your application. `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` then your regular build command and of course remove the quotes. Also you can omit the `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` the driver is detected and loaded automatically.

Comment: You also followed the steps [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) to be able to download the drivers? Or added it to a local maven repository elsewhere? Check if the jar is there and if it is a valid jar.